# Formula not referencing new row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

In Excel 2016 I have a workbook with two tabs -

- Active_Directory_Locations
- SuperTab

In *SuberTab* I use the following formula, copied in to cells A5-A1000 -

```
=IF(OR(Active_Directory_Locations!$D5 = "Totals", Active_Directory_Locations!$D5 = ""), "", Active_Directory_Locations!$D5)
```

This formula works well, however if a row is inserted in to the *Active_Directory_Locations*, the formulas on the *SuperTab* are updated and skip that new row.

For example, if cells `D5`, `D6` and `D7` are referenced and I was to insert a row about row 6 on the *Active_Directory_Locations* tab, those references would change to `D5`, `D7` and `D8`, thus skipping the new row.

Can I amend my formula in anyway to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you never want the value `Active_Directory_Locations!$D5` to change then one thing that should work would be the `INDIRECT` function which evaluates a string value to a cell reference at cell computation time.

Try replacing all references of

```
Active_Directory_Locations!$D5
```

With

```
INDIRECT("Active_Directory_Locations!$D5")
```

As your cell location is now a string value Excel should refrain from automatically updating the cell references.

If you need it to be dynamic then you can combine it with INDEX and CONCATENATE to build your cell reference and use the indirect to evaluate it.